# Unexpected dip on keyframe start

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a snippet which displays a text every 7 seconds. However at the beginning of each animation it performs an unexpected dip which i can't rule out. Can you find what it is?

[Here's the pen.](https://codepen.io/mercurial_providence/pen/MWWrMPK)

```css
.chillquote {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  color: var(--bodyColor);
  height: 4em;
  font-family: var(--usedH-font-stack);
}
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  div:first-of-type {
    /* For increasing performance 
                         ID/Class should've been used. 
                         For a small demo 
                         it's okaish for now */
    animation: showup 7s infinite;
  }

  div:last-of-type {
    width: 0px;
    animation: reveal 7s infinite;
  }

  div:last-of-type span {
    margin-left: -50rem;
    animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes showup {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes slidein {
    0% {
      margin-left: -800px;
    }
    20% {
      margin-left: -800px;
    }
    35% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
  }

  @keyframes reveal {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0px;
    }
    20% {
      opacity: 1;
      width: 0px;
    }
    30% {
      width: auto;
    }
    80% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="chillquote">
  <div>
   Q
  </div>
  <div>
    <span >
                              {{ randomQ.quote }}
                              <i><span style="    font-size: 0.5em;">~ {{ randomQ.author }}</span></i>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `inline-block` to display the all the `divs`.

When the text that appears starts out, you have a `width` of 0 set in the `reveal` animation - when it starts to appear you go from 0 to `auto`.

Since the quote text starts out as multi-line, the baseline changes so the `Q` "drops" down to the text baseline.

I've updated your pen to make the `.chillquote` display block and added classes to the other divs - because `last-child` and `first-child` were also effecting the `.chillquote` div because you never specified a child element.

I also set the final width to a percentage.

```css
.chillquote {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  color: var(--bodyColor);
  height: 4em;
  font-family: var(--usedH-font-stack);
}

.chillquote div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.first {
  /* For increasing performance 
                         ID/Class should've been used. 
                         For a small demo 
                         it's okaish for now */
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
}

div.second {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}

div.second span {
  margin-left: -50rem;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 80%;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chillquote">
  <div class="first">
    Q
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <span>Here is the quote<i> <span style="font-size: 0.5em;">~ Author</span></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/zYYpVQz

**EDIT**

For centered text, we can use `display: flex` and animate the `flex-basis` property to `max-content`.

```css
.chillquote {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: var(--bodyColor);
  height: 4em;
  font-family: var(--usedH-font-stack);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.first {
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
  text-align: right;
}

div.second {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.second span.quote {
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -100vw;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -100vw;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  30% {
    flex-basis: max-content;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    flex-basis: max-content;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chillquote">
  <div class="first">
    Q
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <span class="quote">Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.<i> <span style="font-size: 0.5em;">~ {{ randomQ.author }}</span></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

New CodePen: https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/zYYRzOY

Comment: Thanks, that almost solved the issue! One little thing regarding `width:auto`, I am trying to align this in center, so setting any particular width, like 80% generates a gap if the quote is small string. See [here](https://codepen.io/mercurial_providence/pen/PooEMqr).

Comment: Weird. So it works perfect in Firefox, but not chrome. I'll have to troubleshoot this a little later.